# How to perform group by on multiple columns in a pandas dataframe and predict future values using fbProphet in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate, facebook-prophet

My dataframe looks like following. I am trying to `aggregate(sum)` my amount column based on Date and Group present in `pandas` dataframe. I was able to successfully `aggregate` the column. However, I am not sure how to pass in [fbprophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html#forecasting-growth) to predict the future values based on grouped date and Group. Below is the code for aggregation.
Note: I am beginner in python, please provide explanation with code.

**Data Frame**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date':['2017-01-01', '2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01',
               '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01','2017-02-01','2017-02-01','2017-02-01','2017-02-01','2017-02-01','2017-02-01'],'Group':['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D'],
       'Amount':['12.1','13.2','15.1','10.7','12.9','9.0','5.6','6.7','4.3','2.3','4.0','5.6','7.8','2.3','5.6','8.9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code tried so far:**

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Group','Date'])[['Amount']].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice well-asked question,
it follows https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suffering from a few problems.

## numeric

The 3rd line of your `data` initialization should pass in `float` rather than `str`.
Elide the quotes.
Or, this will fix it:

```
'Amount':[float(n) for n in ['12.1','13.2','15.1','10.7','12.9','9.0','5.6','6.7','4.3','2.3','4.0','5.6','7.8','2.3','5.6','8.9']]}
```

We do this because you *really* don't want `.sum()` to put together 12.1 and 13.2
and come up with `'12.113.2'`.
You'd much prefer `25.3`.

## index

The `grouped` object you computed looks good on the face of it,
but if you inspect the `.dtypes` attribute you'll see
it's only offering the `Amount` column to facebook prophet.
To remedy that, use [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
>>> grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> grouped.dtypes
Group     object
Date      object
Amount   float64
dtype: object
```

But now we see one last fly in the ointment.

## dates

Having opaque categories of `'A'` or `'B'` is fine,
but for `Date` we probably want to know that February or March
comes a certain number of days after January,
rather that leaving opaque `str` labels in that column.

We might have done the type conversion back when we presented the `data` input,
but it's fine to clean it up at this stage, too:

```
import datetime as dt

def to_timestamp(day: str):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(day, '%Y-%m-%d')

grouped['Date'] = grouped.Date.apply(to_timestamp)
```

Having successfully wrangled the shape and types of your data,
you should now be in a good position to let libraries further analyze it.